# Does Jquery Trigger and Bind do that same as Publisher and Subscriber?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have implement simple publisher and subscriber using javascript. Now I came across jquery trigger and bind. Do trigger and bind do the same as publisher and subscriber....

Comment: We can't tell if they are similar or not if you don't supply us with some code to see what they do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, in a way. The event handling which `trigger()` and `bind()` use is a publish/subscribe pattern. But these functions work with jQuery objects only, not with JavaScript objects.